# How to get the java Class to which a method belongs given the method signature?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, antlr, grammar

I am using ANTLR on the Java8 grammar to parse some Android code, and I'm searching for method invocations having the signature `abortBroadcast()`. However, I need to check if `abortBroadcast()` is the method from `BroadcastReceiver` class, not some method from another class. Is there any way I can get the Class to which the `abortBroadcast()` method belongs?

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) to get stack trace - there you can find all function calls in current thread. And for every element call `getMethodName()` to find your `abortBroadcast()`, the `getClassName()` will show you class.

Comment: The Android code is not run, only parsed. Same as parsing it from a text file.

Comment: Well, you are looking for [lexical analysis](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076874/learn-java/lexical-analysis-and-java--part-1.html). I hope it can help you.